# Is there a race consuming stdout from child_process.spawn in node.js?

Tags: node.js, race-condition, spawn

I'm using node.js to [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) a child process and consume its output, using the `child.stdout.on('data')` hook.

`child.stdout` is itself a stream, and over on the [streams page](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) I notice a fat warning informing me that if no handler is registered when a data event arrives, then the data is dropped on the floor.

There is a brief moment between the spawn of my child process, and the registration of my stdout handler.  **Is there a race condition here?**  I don't want my first read to be lost.

It is reasonable to guess that the pipe between parent and child would buffer, but does node guarantee it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `child.stdout.on('data', [...])` latter in the same *turn* (a series of serial statement) as the `child_process.spawn([...])` call to ensure that the listener is there when the IO operations are next handled. Or you could pause the stream `child.stdout.pause()` (in the same turn) and resume it in a latter turn after adding the listener if it is necessary to install the listener in a latter turn.

Comment: Does node not actually spawn my child process until the end of the turn in which `spawn` is called?

Comment: No, it actually spawns it immediately, but no callbacks, such as the one that the output stream for `stdout` receives on data, happen until this turn is over.

Comment: @DanD. Do you have a link to the documentation about the "turn" concept? I'm having trouble finding it on Google or in node source.

Comment: @dpk Actually it not from there, it's from [Mark Miller's E](http://www.erights.org/). See [Game Turns as MicroTransactions](http://www.erights.org/elib/concurrency/turns.html).

Comment: I don't understand what these "turns" are. When I step through the code with a debugger, I see that as soon as the `const x = spawn(...)` statement is executed, `x.pid` is a valid process ID (at least on Windows). Node of course only has control over its threading model, `cmd.exe` or whatever I spawned doesn't give a shit about the event loop. Since `x.stdout` is additionally also already in flowing mode, this results in all the output I'm interested in leaking out.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin JavaScript actually calls these "turns": [_tasks_](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/). But I think the analogy to game turns is more apt. The examples https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options show corrects usage. If your code looks like that and still doesn't work, please ask a question.

Comment: @DanD. I have `const output = new PassThrough; const p = spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'echo', 'foo']); p.pipe(output); return output`, and `output.read()` is always null, whereas starting with `stdio: inherit` or using `spawnSync` results in valid output. All signs point to this being a race, including, most damningly, that `p.pid` is a valid process id immediately after I step over the `spawn` invocation (and before the `pipe` statement or any other event handling code can be evaluated). Could you try out stepping through it or doing `console.log(p.pid)` yourself?